# Using a variable as array-key while filling the array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I want to fill an array with datas from a database table. Now I have to cols in this table, the first is `id_name` and the second `text`. The table currently has 10 rows, but it could also have more.

Now I want the array to be of the following form:
`[value of col "id_name"] => [value of col "text"]`

I tried to the following:

```
while($row_get_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_get_text)) {
    $text = array(
        $row_get_text['id_name'] => $row_get_text['text'],
    );
}
```

And this is the first time, I try to echo the value that belongs to the index of `home_filter_settings_headline`:

```
<div id="s_f"><?php echo $text['home_filter_settings_headline']; ?></div>
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Is it possible do to as I want to? And if so, what is the correct way to to so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row_get_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_get_text)) {
    $text[$row_get_text['id_name']] = $row_get_text['text'];
}
```

Comment: This brings: `Notice: Undefined variable: text in [...]`

Comment: Tried it, brings: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in [...]`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, check the updated answer please

Comment: Now it works as well as the answer by Hedin. Thank you very much too! :)

Comment: Sounds great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert them in double quotes specially for text field,

```
while($row_get_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_get_text)) {
    $id_name = $row_get_text['id_name'];
    $text_f = $row_get_text['text'];
    $text = array(
        "$id_name" => "$text_f",
    );
}
```

Comment: This brings: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in [...]`

Comment: Tried it, this brings: `Notice: Undefined index: home_filter_settings_headline in [...]`

Comment: Are you sure both of these values are echoing correctly I mean they exist.

Comment: Yeah, if I insert echo `$row_get_text_by_lang['id_name'];` and `echo $row_get_text_by_lang['text_de'];` into the while, it echoes both values.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$result = []
while($row_get_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_get_text)) {
    $result[$row_get_text['id_name']] = $row_get_text['text']
}
```

Comment: This brings: `Notice: Undefined index: home_filter_settings_headline in [...]`

Comment: It worked, there was just one `;` missing. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much correct, however try making these changes
chose `text1` tor `text2` depending on your need. I wasn't sure which one is your requirement.

```
$text1 = array();
$text2 = array();
while($row_get_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_get_text)) {
    $text1[] = array(
        $row_get_text['id_name'] => $row_get_text['text']
    );
    $text2[$row_get_text['id_name']] = $row_get_text['text'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution with "text1" brings: `Notice: Undefined index: home_filter_settings_headline in [...]` in the line, where I want to echo the value of the index `home_filter_settings_headline`. The solution with "text2" brings: `Notice: Undefined index: skill (platzhalter) in [...]`. `skill (platzhalter)` is the value of the col `text` from the database table, and this occurs for every row of the database table.

Comment: I have tested this. It works. As for the error, it seems you are using an incorrect index.